Microsoft ImageList Control from MSCOMCTL.OCX does not contain images at runtime in 64-bit Office
The latest versions of 64-bit Microsoft Office allow us to use ActiveX controls from 32-bit Microsoft Windows Common Controls pack (MSCOMCTL.OCX) due to some enhancements implemented specially for this control pack. However, my tests show that Microsoft ImageList Control does not work properly in 64-bit Access apps. I can upload images into this control at design time, but it seems they do not exist at run time.
I figured this out while trying to use the images from Microsoft ImageList with another ActiveX control I have the source code for. As we know, Microsoft ImageList is a wrapper for the native Windows ImageList functionality. I got the API image list handle from the Micrsoft ImageList control I attached to my ActiveX, and then requested the number of images and their sizes with the ImageList_GetImageCount and ImageList_GetIconSize functions. It turned out that the number of images in the ImageList control and their width/height equal 0 at run time, though the images definitely exist at design time.
As I see, this problem appears only if I use Microsoft ImageList in 64-bit Office. The same ImageList-based app works "as is" without any problems in 32-bit Office.
Is it a known issue of Microsoft ImageList Control in 64-bit Office? Is there a way to make this control work in 64-bit Office apps?
